# Custom Transition Animation Causing Navigation Bar to Animate

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I am implementing a custom transition animation between view controllers, but for some reason my navigation Bar is getting animated along with the transition animation. Is this somehow a auto layout issue? I'm not sure how it would be. 
Here is the code I am using to display and dismiss the view controllers with a custom transition.

I would like the navigation bar to not be animated, any ideas as to why this is happening?

```
-(void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
{
    // Grab the from and to view controllers from the context
    UIViewController *fromViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
    UIViewController *toViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];



    if (self.presenting) {
        fromViewController.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

        [transitionContext.containerView addSubview:fromViewController.view];
        [transitionContext.containerView addSubview:toViewController.view];

        int frameHeight = fromViewController.view.frame.size.height;
        CGRect startFrame = fromViewController.view.frame;
        startFrame.origin.y = frameHeight;
        toViewController.view.frame = startFrame;

        //create a view with the same background color to cover up background on bounce effect
        UIView *bottomCover = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, startFrame.size.height-30, startFrame.size.width, 30)];
        [bottomCover setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.956 green:0.962 blue:0.956 alpha:1]];
        [transitionContext.containerView insertSubview:bottomCover belowSubview:toViewController.view];

        __block CGRect endFrame = toViewController.view.frame;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:[self transitionDuration:transitionContext] delay:0 usingSpringWithDamping:.75 initialSpringVelocity:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
            endFrame.origin.y = 0;
            toViewController.view.frame = endFrame;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [bottomCover removeFromSuperview];
            toViewController.view.frame = endFrame;
            [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
        }];

    }
    else {
        toViewController.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

        [transitionContext.containerView addSubview:toViewController.view];
        [transitionContext.containerView addSubview:fromViewController.view];

        CGRect endFrame = toViewController.view.frame;
        endFrame.origin.y = 0;
        fromViewController.view.frame = endFrame;


        [UIView animateWithDuration:[self transitionDuration:transitionContext] delay:0 usingSpringWithDamping:.9 initialSpringVelocity:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{

            int frameHeight = toViewController.view.frame.size.height;
            CGRect startFrame = fromViewController.view.frame;
            startFrame.origin.y = frameHeight;
            fromViewController.view.frame = startFrame;

        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
            //Because there is a bug in Xcode apparently.
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:toViewController.view];
        }];

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using a modal transition? Or is this a navigation controller push or pop?

Comment: Modal transition @bdrell